# Python Parseing String by Single Quotes

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to Parse the following string:

EDITED to account for spaces...

```
['THE LOCATION', 'THE NAME', 'THE JOB', 'THE AREA')]
```

Right now I use regular expressions and split the data with the comma into a list

InfoL = re.split(",", Info)

However my output is

```
'THE LOCATION'
'THE NAME'
'THE JOB'
'THE AREA')]
```

Looking to have the output as follows

```
THE LOCATION
THE NAME
THE JOB
THE AREA
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What's with the closing brackets? Is that a legitimate part of the input, or just a typo?

Comment: Yes the closing brackets should be there.

Comment: Are you running this program VIA IDLE? or are you running it through the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use `strip()` to remove the unwanted characters:

```
In [18]: s="['LOCATION', 'NAME', 'JOB', 'AREA')]"

In [19]: print '\n'.join(tok.strip("[]()' ") for tok in s.split(','))
LOCATION
NAME
JOB
AREA
```

Like your original solution, this will break if any of strings are allowed to contain commas.

P.S. If that closing parenthesis in your example is a typo, you might be able to use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
In [22]: print '\n'.join(ast.literal_eval(s))
LOCATION
NAME
JOB
AREA
```

Comment: How would you do this but keep it in a list?

Answer (score 0):

```
InfoL = re.split("[, '()\[\]]*", Info)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can you explain what python does when it sees this?

Comment: It's worth noting that this regex *might* be a little too fragile. For example, if one of the strings were to contain a space, this will break.

Comment: Hmmm I see what you mean... My List is now split up to much... For example 'The Location' becomes 'The', 'Location" in the list when it should be 'The Location'

Answer (score 0):

try this code snippet :

```
import re
tmpS = "['THE LOCATION', 'THE NAME', 'THE JOB', 'THE AREA')]"
tmpS = re.sub('[^\w\s,]+', '', tmpS)
print tmpS # Result -> 'THE LOCATION, THE NAME, THE JOB, THE AREA'
for s in tmpS.split(','):
     print s.strip()


O/P:
THE LOCATION
THE NAME
THE JOB
THE AREA
```